# Imrpove the following code without if/else

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to avoid using multiple if and else condition here

```
  if (decode) {
                Imagepath = bucket + "/" + key;
                Result.pages.push({                         
                        Id: Processid,
                        ValidTicket: decode ? true : false
                });
        } else {
                //checking for barcode if qr code is not present
                Quagga.decodeSingle({
                        src: filename,
                        numOfWorkers: 0, // Needs to be 0 when used within node 
                        decoder: {
                                readers: ['code_128_reader',
                                        'ean_reader',
                                        'ean_8_reader',
                                        'code_39_reader',
                                        'code_39_vin_reader',
                                        'codabar_reader',
                                        'upc_reader',
                                        'upc_e_reader',
                                        'i2of5_reader'
                                ] // List of active readers 
                        },
                }, function (result, error) {
                        //if guaggajs returns the result
                        if (result) {
                                console.log("bar code done");
                                //sometimes result is not empty but codeResult is empty
                                if (result.codeResult) {
                                        var barcode = result.codeResult.code;
                                        var Imagepath = '';
                                        Imagepath = bucket + "/" + key;
                                        Result.pages.push({
                                                Id: Processid,
                                                ValidTicket: barcode ? true : false
                                        });
                                        console.log("final array is" + Result);
                                } else {
                                        var Imagepath = '';
                                        Imagepath = bucket + "/" + key;
                                        Result.pages.push({
                                                Id: Processid,
                                                ValidTicket: false
                                        });

                                }
                        } else {
                                var Imagepath = '';
                                Imagepath = bucket + "/" + key;
                                Result.pages.push({
                                        Id: Processid,
                                        ValidTicket: false
                                });

                        }
                });
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove `Quagga.decodeSingle()` callbacks `if...else` conditions?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, it is best to explain what the code does.  This is especially true in the title.

Comment: @Tushar exactly

Answer (score 1):

I would separate them out into functions to make the code more readable. So the first if/else would become:

```
if (decode)
  doDecode()
else
  doEncodeSingle();
```

I would also break the `doDocdeSingle` up:

```
Quagga.decodeSingle({...},
  handleDecodeResult );
```

The last if/else is currently structured as:

```
if (result) {
  if (result.codeResult) {
    // Handle Code
  } else {
    // Handle no-code
  }
} else {
  // No result
}
```

I often find it cleaner to reverse the condition and structure it as:

```
if (!result) {
  // No result
} else if (result.codeResult) {
  // Handle Code
} else {
  // Handle no-code
}
```

Which removes a level of nesting. Again I would try and make each if section a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove one else block like this:

```
var barcode = '';
if (result && result.codeResult) {
    console.log("bar code done");
    //sometimes result is not empty but codeResult is empty
    barcode = result.codeResult.code;
}
var Imagepath = '';
Imagepath = bucket + "/" + key;
Result.pages.push({
    Id: Processid,
    ValidTicket: barcode ? true : false
});
console.log("final array is" + Result);
```

Comment: As the barcode actual value *result.codeResult.code* is never used, why don't turn the variable to a boolean?